# asp.net mvc : custom ViewModel form post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Just starting out with ASP.NET MVC and have come across a stumbling block already.

The situation is that I have a custom ViewModel to pass to the view, which contains a list of items to be rated ( will be using the jQuery star rating ), so these are created using the radio button helper, to have the same name, just different value, and these render no problem.

I have absolutely no idea how to actually get that back into the post version of my action, however.  I just get a 'no parameterless constructor' error. I don't want to use the forms collection - I want my data to remain class based.

Has anybody had to do anything similar?

Many thanks for any advice.

=======================================================================

UPDATE ( basic code included ):

```
    In the HomeController:

    public class MyViewModel 
    {
        public MyViewModel(List<Thing> things ) // Thing.cs contains properties name and rating
        {
            this.Things = things;           
        }

        public List<Thing> Things { get; private set; }
    }


   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();

        Thing t;

        t = new Thing();
        t.name = "One";
        t.rating = 1;
        things.Add(t);

        t = new Thing();
        t.name = "Two";
        t.rating = 2;
        things.Add(t);

        return View(new MyViewModel(things));  
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index( MyViewModel vm)
    {
        return View();
    }       

    and in the Index page ( Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Controllers.MyViewModel>" )

 <% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
    <ul>
    <%  for( int t = 0; t<Model.Things.Count; t++)
        {%>
            <li>
                <% for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                   {
                       MyProject.Thing thing = Model.Things[i];
                       %>
               <%=Html.RadioButton(String.Format("Things[{0}]", t), i)%>
                   <% } %>

            </li>
    <%  }%>
    </ul>    
    <input type="submit" value="submit me" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a parameterless constructor for the ViewModel. Also, the names of the properties need to match up with the names/ IDs of the controls.

You may need to simplify a little, or even write you're own model binder.

An explanation of model binders and their use [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx).

A good article on writing a model binder [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx).

I think you'll need to write your own binder because you're trying to build an array of a complex type. The complex type on it's own would be fine, it's where it's in the array that the problems begin.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh, the sweet, sweet smell of success...

I didn't need to do anything complicated like use a custom model binder, I simply had the wrong property names in the index rabiobutton loop.

Knew it couldn't be that difficult...

Now I just need to figure out how to have a default radiobutton so I don't need to validate.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When your form is posted, only the selected radio button value will be posted back to the server.

You should be able to use the `UpdateModel()` method to automatically update your model class with the values posted back from the form.

Comment: I can't even get to that point though.

In the post's action, I'm passing in an instance of the class I gave the view, but it has the runtime error above when the form is submitted.